# Trouble creating algorithm that modifies elements of a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having trouble editing the values of a 2d char array.

```
char[,] chrRaster = new char[4, 5];
```

After adding values to the array and printing it to the console, I get:

```
// Input example:
*****
**.**
*****
****.
```

I am trying to make an algorithm that **replaces every '*' that is beside, under or above a '.'** by a '.' and then printing this to the console.

```
// Output after algorithm example:
**.**
*...*
**.*.
***..
```

I have tried converting the 2d char array to a 2d string array and then using `IndexOf('*')` to replace every `'*'` that is beside, under or above a `'.'`, and I also tried calculating this using a number of `if` and `for` loops without any luck.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variablen
            int intTestgeval = 0; // Number of times you want program to repeat 
            int intN = 0;         // Number of rows
            int intM = 0;         // Number of coloms
            char chrGrond;        // Used to store '*' or '.'
            char[,] chrRaster;    // 2d char array used to store all values 

            // Code
            try
            {
                intTestgeval = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Number of times program will repeat           

                if(intTestgeval > 150) // Program can not repeat more then 150 times 
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {                
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            intN = Controle(intN);                          // Number of rows ophalen
            intM = Controle(intM);                          // Number of Coloms ophalen

            chrRaster = new char[intN, intM];               // Initializing array with user input


            for (int intR = 0; intR < intTestgeval; intR++)  // Print 2d array to console
            {
                for(int intY = 0; intY < intN; intY++)
                {
                    for(int intZ = 0; intZ < intM; intZ++)
                    {
                        chrGrond = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);

                        chrRaster[intY, intZ] = chrGrond;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }


                instorten[intR] = Instorten(chrRaster, intN, intM); // Ignore this part, that's another part of my assignment not related to my question.
            }
        }

        static int Controle( int intX )
        {
            try
            {
                intX = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (intX > 150 || intX < 1) // Length of row and colom can not exceed 20 and can not go lower then 1
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                return intX;
            }
            catch                           // Program will off if value does not meet requirements
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
                return intX;
            }            
        }

  // It is this part of the program I need help with. This is what I tried but can't get any further
        static int Instorten(char[,] chrRaster, int intN, int intM)
        {
            for (int intY = 0; intY < intN; intY++)
            {
                for (int intZ = 0; intZ < intM; intZ++)
                {
                    if(chrRaster[intY, intZ] == '.' && chrRaster[intY, intZ + 1] == '*' || chrRaster[intY, intZ] == '*' && chrRaster[intY, intZ + 1] == '.')
                    {

                    }                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            int intm = 0;
            return intm;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: What % of your grade is this assignment worth?

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can see what you've tried?  People here are happy to help developers who are getting errors in code they've implemented.

Comment: @Jon my teacher isn't giving a grade on this, he just advised us that we make this exercise. And I'll put my code in a second.

Comment: If you're not getting graded, why on earth would you not work it on your own? Or ask the teacher for some direction? The only way to get decent at writing code is by, you know, actually writing code.

Comment: @ToaNarumi I was half joking, because your question is written like a college assignment and you've put no effort into showing us your code or what you've tried. It just came across as if you are finding someone online to help you write your assignment for you, which as the poster above mentioned, is not going to help you learn anything.

Comment: But it sounds like you've made some attempts. It would be helpful if you could share some of those as they might be *close* and need just a little polish.

Comment: @ToaNarumi show your code and no one will utter a word !

Comment: @Jon I have put effort in to it. I have just updated this thread with all my code. Apoligies that it's still in dutch, but basically intN represents 4 and intM represents 5. I didn't put all my code on this thread because I thought it woudn't look tidy.

Comment: can you just change variables names to english ?

Comment: Ok, thanks  Zain will do.

Comment: @ToaNarumi please see my answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to make a copy of the array and then iterate over it, examining each item. If the item is a `'.'`, then update the neighbors of this item in the original array.

To determine the neighbors, we simply add one to the row to get the neighbor below, subtract one from the row to get the neighbor above, and similarly we can get the right and left neighbors by adding/subtracting from the column value. Of course we need to ensure that we're inside the bounds of the array before doing anything.

We could write a method with this logic that might look like:

```
private static void ExposeDotNeighbors(char[,] input)
{
    if (input == null) return;

    // Make a copy of the input array that we can iterate over
    // so that we don't analyze items that we've already changed
    var copy = (char[,]) input.Clone();

    for (var row = 0; row <= copy.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col <= copy.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
        {
            if (copy[row, col] == '.')
            {
                // Update neighbors in original array
                // Above = [row - 1, col], Below = [row + 1, col],
                // Left = [row, col - 1], Right = [row, col + 1]
                // Before updating, make sure we're inside the array bounds
                if (row > 0) input[row - 1, col] = '.';
                if (row < input.GetUpperBound(0)) input[row + 1, col] = '.';
                if (col > 0) input[row, col - 1] = '.';
                if (col < input.GetUpperBound(1)) input[row, col + 1] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can also write some helper methods that will give us the initial array and to print an array to the console (also one that will write a header to the console):

```
private static char[,] GetInitialArray()
{
    var initialArray = new char[4, 5];

    for (var row = 0; row <= initialArray.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col <= initialArray.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
        {
            if ((row == 1 && col == 2) || (row == 3 && col == 4))
            {
                initialArray[row, col] = '.';
            }
            else
            {
                initialArray[row, col] = '*';
            }
        }
    }

    return initialArray;
}

private static void PrintArrayToConsole(char[,] input)
{
    if (input == null) return;

    for (var row = 0; row <= input.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col <= input.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
        {
            Console.Write(input[row, col]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private static void WriteHeader(string headerText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
    {
        Console.Write(new string('═', Console.WindowWidth));
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine('╔' + new string('═', headerText.Length + 2) + '╗');
    Console.WriteLine($"║ {headerText} ║");
    Console.WriteLine('╚' + new string('═', headerText.Length + 2) + '╝');
}
```

With these helper methods, we can then write code like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var chrRaster = GetInitialArray();

    WriteHeader("Before");
    PrintArrayToConsole(chrRaster);

    ExposeDotNeighbors(chrRaster);

    WriteHeader("After");
    PrintArrayToConsole(chrRaster);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

And out output would look like:

[image]

---

I noticed that you also appear to be getting the values from the user, and using `try/catch` blocks to validate the input. A better approach might be to write a helper method that takes in a string that represents the "prompt" to the user, and a validation method that can be used to validate the input. With this, we can keep asking the user for input until they enter something valid.

Below are methods that get an integer and a character from the user, and allow the caller to pass in a function that can be used for validation. These methods will not return until the user enters valid input:

```
private static char GetCharFromUser(string prompt, Func<char, bool> validator = null)
{
    char result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
        result = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    } while (!(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    Console.WriteLine();
    return result;
}

private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
                !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

private static void ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(int cursorTop, string message)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

We can then re-write our `GetInitialArray` method to use these methods to get the dimensions and values from the user:

```
private static char[,] GetInitialArray()
{
    const int maxCols = 20;
    const int maxRows = 20;

    var numCols = GetIntFromUser(
        $"How many columns do you want (1 - {maxCols}): ",
        i => i > 0 && i <= maxCols);

    var numRows = GetIntFromUser(
        $"How many rows do you want (1 - {maxRows}): ",
        i => i > 0 && i <= maxRows);

    var initialArray = new char[numRows, numCols];

    for (var row = 0; row <= initialArray.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col <= initialArray.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
        {
            initialArray[row, col] = GetCharFromUser(
                $"Enter value for [{row}, {col}] ('.' or '*'): ",
                c => c == '.' || c == '*');
        }
    }

    return initialArray;
}
```

And now our output might look like this:

[image]

If you try it, notice that you cannot enter an illegal value. The program just waits for you to read the instructions and enter a valid number or character. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm that does what you want. I have tried to explain my code in the comments. The output will match what you're looking for.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char STAR = '*';
        char DOT = '.';

        var input = new char[,]
        {
            { STAR,STAR,STAR,STAR,STAR},
            { STAR,STAR,DOT,STAR,STAR},
            { STAR,STAR,STAR,STAR,STAR},
            { STAR,STAR,STAR,STAR,DOT}
        };

        var output = new char[4, 5];

        // Copy each from input to output, checking if it touches a '.'
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y ++)
            {
                if (input[x, y] == STAR)
                {
                    var isDot = false;
                    // Check left
                    if (x > 0)
                        isDot = input[x - 1, y] == DOT;

                    // Check right
                    if (x < 3)
                        isDot = isDot || (input[x + 1, y] == DOT);

                    // Check above
                    if (y > 0)
                        isDot = isDot || (input[x, y - 1] == DOT);

                    // Check below
                    if (y < 4)
                        isDot = isDot || (input[x, y + 1]) == DOT;

                    output[x, y] = isDot ? DOT : STAR;
                }
                else
                {
                    output[x, y] = input[x, y];
                }
            }
        }

        // Print output
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y ++)
            {
                Console.Write(output[x, y]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. In the future, I'll put all of my code in my thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this :

```
using System;
public class chars
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[,] charArray = new char[,] {{'*','*','*','*','*'}, 
                                         {'*','*','.','*','*'},
                                         {'*','*','*','*','*'},
                                         {'*','*','*','*','.'}};
        int[,] holdIndex = new int[4, 5];

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)  // get allindexes containing '.'
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
            {
                if(charArray[i,j] == '.')
                    holdIndex[i,j] = 1;
                else
                    holdIndex[i,j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
            {
                if(holdIndex[i,j] == 1)
                {
                    if(i!=0)
                        charArray[i-1,j] = '.';  //up
                    if(j!=0)
                        charArray[i,j-1] = '.';  // left
                    if(j!=4)
                        charArray[i,j+1] = '.';  //right 
                    if(i!=3)
                        charArray[i+1,j] = '.';  //down
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(charArray[i,j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```